# Highcharts - Display out of range data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to display sparse time series data in highcharts, and would like to be able to include lines indicating that there is data outside the displayed date range. For example, if I have a chart with the following data series:

```
    |                        |     
    |           D---E        |     
    |          /     \       |     
A---|---B     /       \      |     
    |    \   /         \     |     
    |     \ /           F----|---G 
    |      C                 |
```

... and with the viewing window indicated by the vertical lines, I would like to chart to include the portions of the data lines between point A & B, and the portion of the line between point F & G that fall within the window. That way viewers will know that there is data beyond the current date range. The desired chart would look like:

```
    |                        |
    |           D---E        |
    |          /     \       |
    |---B     /       \      |
    |    \   /         \     |
    |     \ /           F----|
    |      C                 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Plot Bands can be created on the chart like this.

```
 xAxis: {
        plotLines: [{
            color: '#FF0000',
            width: 2,
            value: 5.5
        }]
    }
```

to show only data within the range it can be done either by updating the range on the xAxis using min and max keys within the xAxis. Or buy updating the series data to remove those specific points from the data.

MAX http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max
MIN http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.min

there are methods that highcharts supplies that lets you update Axis and Series options that are also contained in the api documentation